# Node telegram bot api - disable processing of updates sent before the bot starts

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I, have this issue: when I start the bot it immediately starts looking for updates. However, in my particular case (especially during the developing) this can be very frustrating and uncomfortable. There is a way to tell the bot to process the update sent after the starting of the bot itself?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Telegram to "forget" those updates. This is how you would do it:

1. Send a request to: `https://api.telegram.org/bot$TELEGRAM_TOKEN/getUpdates`
2. Get the `message_id` of the last element (pop) of the result array
3. Send another request `https://api.telegram.org/bot$TELEGRAM_TOKEN/getUpdates?offset=$OFFSET` where $OFFSET is the `message_id + 1`

This is a **stateless** way of clearing pending requests. You can use curl,the browser or a request library (recommended) to do this. You can do this with node-telegram-bot-api but I don't recommend since you will have to create 2 bot instances,  1 polling and 1 non polling to clear the updates which is not a good practice since ntba doesn't decouple its methods in a different class.

So in **pseudocode** code:

```js
const TOKEN = 'MY_TOKEN'

async function clearUpdates(token) {
  const { result } = await request.get(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/getUpdates`).json()
  
  return await request.get(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/getUpdates?offset=${result[result.length - 1].message_id + 1}`)
}
```

Now run clearUpdates before starting your bot.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this solution in the afternoon.